# How to get the upper bound of expectation of its characteristic function $E(e^{tX})\le?$

Tags: real-analysis, probability

For a random variable $X=0$ or $1$, we know that
$$P(X=1)\ge 1-\gamma$$
(i.e. $P(X=0)\le \gamma$).

How to get the upper bound of expectation of its characteristic function
$$E(e^{tX})\le?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite certain what you mean but I think you're saying that the random variable $X$ can only take the values $0$ or $1$. If this is the case then if $a:=\mathrm{Pr} (X=0)$ we have $\mathrm{Pr}(X=1) = 1-a$ for $0\leqslant a \leqslant 1$. Then \begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} e^{tX} &= a +(1-a)e^t.
\end{align*} You can see that if $a<1$ then $\mathbb{E} e^{tX}$ is unbounded.